# Text isn't always altered properly in plugin after resize

Tags: xaml, rendering, awesomium

I wrote an Awesomium 1.7.2 plugin that displays a bunch of text and contains a few buttons.  While the plugin functions fine, I have some strange display issues.

I have a separate program that I sometimes "Dock" at the top of my computer screen.  When I do that, the text inside my Awesomium window gets warped a little (see screenshots below).  That's because that window THINKS that it's maximized, but the screen has been compressed by 20 to 30 pixels; whatever the height of that separate, docked window is.

Other programs seem to be smart enough to render text appropriately when I add/remove my docked program.  Also, when I view these web pages directly in a web-browser, they get resized properly after the dock change.  It's only when they're inside of this Awesomium control where they don't respond properly to another program being docked.  How can I make my html controls behave this way inside of the Awesomium window?

Update: I tried 1.7.3 as well, but the problem still exists.

Update: I also posted this question on [answers.awesomium.com](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/3592/button-text-is-altered-in-awesomium.html) and [awesomium.zendesk.com](https://awesomium.zendesk.com/requests/305), but that hasn't helped.

SCREENSHOTS

Maximized without a docked program present:
[image: Maximized without a docked program present]

Maximized WITH a docked program present and warped, compressed text:
[image: Maximized WITH a docked program present and warped text]

Comment: What's probably happening is that it is rendering to an image and then not re-rendering when its window size changes. What .NET UI stack are you hosting this in? (you might also try WebControl.Reload to see if that solves the issue, though you would have to detect the window size change yourself.)